# View under status bar in iPhone X simulator distorted

Tags: ios, xcode9, iphone-x

I have recently upgraded to xcode 9 and run my project on simulator iPhone X and the view under status bar is distorted. In other phone everything is working fine.

Distorted view in iPhone X

[image]

Undistorted view in other phones

[image]

Comment: Are you using interface builder ? Are you using Safe Area?

Comment: I am using storyboard. Project was build in xcode 8 and at that there was no Safe Area.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use Safe Area, you can pin it to the Top Layout Guide with 0 constant:

[image]

Or you can enable Safe Area in File inspector of a View Controller, it's backward deployable back to iOS 9, and again pin the top with 0 constant.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

set view's Y as 44. Status bar height is 44. If navigation bar is there, make it 145. I hope it will work